# hibernate.cfg.xml not found exception, was working with configure() yesterday

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

Loading a hibernate based runnable jar on ec2, I am suddenly getting a hibernate.cfg.xml not found exception.

```
233  [main] FATAL com.mcruiseon.server.hibernate.ReadOnlyOperations  - Unable to create SessionFactory for Hibernate
233  [main] FATAL com.mcruiseon.server.hibernate.ReadOnlyOperations  - ./hibernate.cfg.xml not found
234  [main] FATAL com.mcruiseon.server.hibernate.ReadOnlyOperations  - org.hibernate.HibernateException: ./hibernate.cfg.xml not found
org.hibernate.HibernateException: ./hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1929)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1910)
```

Here is a snapshot of the folder containing the cfg.xml file.
[image]

I am trying to initialize hibernate using the following code snippet. It was working with just `configure()`, for some reason it just stopped working.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("./hibernate.cfg.xml");
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder().buildServiceRegistry());
```

Edit : Even worse, I started getting a log4j issue now. I am just having a bad day.

```
INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@480457
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate(Log4jLogger.java:58)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.isEnabled(Log4jLogger.java:39)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.tracev(Logger.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause : When we move from Hibernate 3.5 to 4.0, we should not replace the jpa library from 3.5. I also had a clash in using incorrect log4j. I had to use a "under development" log4j 1.2.12, instead of 1.2.9 (stable) release to get this working. All in all upgrades are painful and give all kinds of crazy side effects.

Thankyou @Arham and @Raunak, you have been most useful. Good hints.

Answer (score 1):

I can't visualize what is your root directory here. But if ../mcruiseOn/mcruiseOserver/ is root then try putting it there. And mention it as "/hibernate.cfg.xml". There is nothing wrong with your hibernate xml except the path where it's placed.

Comment: could you mention in your question the way you are compiling and running your code? commandline?? IDE??

Comment: my question was how do you run it, could you show the commandline info? it should be in your classpath and I guess your root is not same as your classpath else it would have run successfully.

Comment: sudo  java -classpath carpoolServer_lib/ -jar carpoolServer.jar

Comment: so put it in carpoolServer_lib/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing following this:

1) Try checking the System permission for hibernate.cfg.xml if, it has the rw permission or not

2) Instead try giving in the absolute path that may help.

Comment: Could you try calling the configure method without any arguments?